# Calling #[] on a ruby method

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

Create a method that can be called in this manner

`some_named_method(string_1, string_2, int_1, int_2)[Integer]`

I've just learned that if a method is being called like so `some_named_method[80]` - that method is a Proc / lambda (? still a little unsure of this any elaboration would be great)

Guidelines are, arguments are optional, in groups of two, based on the tests provided, but the number in brackets will always be present. It is used to create an Array, which is operated on, depending on the params being passed in.. So ->

`some_named_method[Integer]` # => [0..Integer]

`some_named_method('Hey', 'There')[Integer]` # some operations based on the string arguments and => [0..Integer]

some_named_method('Hey', 'There', 3, 5)[Integer]

How do you make a lambda have optional arguments in this way?

**ANSWER** (I think)

When a method is being called in this way, `some_named_method(*args)[Integer]`, one of two things is happening. Either the method returns an array, so `#[]` is being called on that array, returning whatever object is at the specified index

**OR**

that method contains a proc / lambda, and whatever is inside the `#[some_arguement]` is being passed as an argument(s) to that proc / lambda

Comment: It’s called a method and it is *extremely* common: `def foo; 42 end; foo() #=> 42`. Unfortunately function and method are often used interchangeably by some.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, but that method could be anything that takes the splat operator and returns an object with the `[]` method, like `def fizz_buzz_custom(*a) a end`

Comment: `f(x)[y]` is the same as `z = f(x); z[y]` so your method could return anything that `respond_to? :[]`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - You do not understand my question. -- I'm trying to understand how `foo[Integer]` is used, where foo is a function.

Comment: @JamesGibsonWeber You’re right, I didn’t understand because the question was not clear to me.

Comment: So `foo()` must return some object, which have a method `[]`. For example array. Notice that `foo()[x]` is the same as `foo[x]` if foo is not taking the args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want a method that takes any number of arguments, and returns an object that will create a range of numbers when the `[]` method is used.

This method takes any number of arguments (using the `*` splat operator), and then returns a proc, which `[]` can be used on.

```
def some_named_function(*args)
  proc do |length|
    # Do something with the args?
    (0..length).to_a
  end
end
```

And then it can be used like this:

```
some_named_function[3] # => [0, 1, 2, 3]
some_named_function('optional', 'args')[1] # => [0, 1]
```